# DEP0600: Deployment failed. XmlException – Data at the root level is invalid

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, uwp

When I deploy a UWP from VS 2017, I’m seeing the following error:

```
DEP0600: Deployment failed. XmlException - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 24, position 11.
```

Any clues on how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

After much debugging and Binging, an SDE pointed out that I was hitting a known bug in Windows 10 Creators Update – which will be fixed in the upcoming Fall Creators update. At install time, all of the installed package are enumerated to see if the package has already been installed. This enumeration fails if the **installed app’s AppxManifest.xml file is malformed.**
I had several test apps installed on my machine, some deployed with Visual Studio, some installed with PowerShell using the command:

```
Add-AppxPackage -Register .\PackageLayout\AppxManifest.xml
```

After uninstalling several of the test apps, I was able to deploy my app with Visual Studio 2017 without problems.